# Magento manual order creation in Admin, Payment Method Paypal express checkout is not visible

Tags: magento, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using magento with paypal express checkout.I have configured it.

But when I create the orders in admin I am not getting this option there. 
How can I do this?
[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Magento payment methods does not support using it in admin. PayPal Express method does not support it also.

P.S. After creating order customer are redirected to PayPal. If you create order for customer he will not be redirected and can not pay for order.
You need to search for payment method that allow repayment (link to pay).

Payment method has a parameter

```
protected $_canUseInternal              = false;
```

but changing it to true is not enought :)

Answer (score 1):

We encountered the same issue and didn't find a solution that automated handling PayPal payments for orders created via the Magento backend.  What we did in the end is a manual process and requires several steps for the salesperson, but it allows us to keep our orders and their payment types organized and accurate.

We created a custom payment method called "PayPal - Manual Invoicing".  It's configured to only appear on the adminhtml order creation screen.  Functionally it effectively does nothing other than mark the payment type of the order for manual invoicing--after the order is created the salesperson has to go to PayPal and send the customer an invoice.  And again when the invoice is paid the salesperson has to invoice the order in Magento manually.

For a decent tutorial on making a payment method take a look at this: http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-create-custom-payment-method

The tutorial walks you through extending the core `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract` class, adding your new payment method to the Payment Methods, and adding the necessary UI components.

Comment: Did you run into issues with IPN? We are doing something similar, and Paypal is trying to update orders via IPN and complaining that they are failing.